rise in jupyter truncates in height in fenced syntax highlight code
I added the following code into a jupyter notebook cell:
# this is just a demo
# line 2
# line 3
# line 4

def fib(n):
    if n<1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fib(5))

The code was rendered correctly:

However, when I launched RISE to present my notebook as a slider, the code was truncated, and only a few lines were shown:

Is there a way to make the mentioned code visible in RISE?

P.S. I am using rise-5.7.1 with jupyter 1.0.0 and jupyter_core-4.6.3 under Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) on Windows 64 bits. In the presentation view, always only 10 lines of code are displayed; if I want to see more lines, I have to use a mousewheel.

Is the "rise" presentation just fixing the height based on your screen that presumably would not enable scrolling as it is a slide show?

IMO, it would help if you mentioned the Jupyter and RISE versions.

I am using rise-5.7.1 with jupyter 1.0.0 and jupyter_core-4.6.3 under Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) on Windows 64 bits. In the presentaiton view, always only 10 lines of code are displayed; if I want to see more lines, I have to use mousewheel
